# MySQL Inner Join two tables and insert row from one table to other on matching row field

Tags: mysql, magento

So, I have to build a query to add a new row in `customer_entity_varchar` for each `entity_id` containing the data from the `customer_address_entity_varchar` table.

Table structure is as such:

```
+----------+----------------+--------------+-----------+---------+
| value_id | entity_type_id | attribute_id | entity_id |  value  |
+----------+----------------+--------------+-----------+---------+
|  132     |              1 |      5       |     12    | John    |
|  133     |              1 |      7       |     12    | Doe     |
|  134     |              1 |     241      |     12    | 8675309 |
+----------+----------------+--------------+-----------+---------+
```

`value_id` is autoincrement, generated by the table.

`entity_type_id` will always be 1 (varchar).

`attribute_id` should be set to 315.

`entity_id` will match between tables.

value of `customer_address_entity_varchar`.value where `customer_address_entity_varchar.attribute_id = 24` should be written in as a new row to `customer_entity_varchar`.

Let me know if you need any more information.

Here is a SQL fiddle with an attempt at an INSERT query solution:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42ffdf/1

Comment: `update` cannot create/insert new rows. it can only modify rows that already exist. you probably want `insert into ... select from`.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I have updated the post with a SQL fiddle. The last INSERT statement is what needs to be worked on, it needs to select all rows from the address table and replace entity_id and value with the field data in the row.

Answer (score 0):

Having researched it further and tested it out, the answer I was looking for is:

```
INSERT INTO customer_entity_varchar 
(`entity_type_id`, `attribute_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) 
SELECT 1 AS `entity_type_id`, 315 AS `attribute_id`, `entity_id`, `value` 
FROM customer_address_entity_varchar WHERE `attribute_id` = 24
```